# Agrupar dados de tabelas com INNER JOIN

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu quero criar enquetes no meu site mais estou com um problema para relacionar duas tabelas. As perguntas estão se repetindo.

Tabela `pergunta`

> id_pergunta = 1: o que você acha do Samsung s8?
>
> id_pergunta = 2: o que você acha do iPhone 8?

Tabela `opção`

> id_pergunta = 1:  id_opcao = 1: bom
>
> id_pergunta = 1:  id_opcao = 2: ruim
>
> id_pergunta = 1:  id_opcao = 3: péssimo
>
> id_pergunta = 2:  id_opcao = 4: bom
>
> id_pergunta = 2:  id_opcao = 5: ruim
>
> id_pergunta = 2:  id_opcao = 6: péssimo

Como eu quero exibir:

```
o que você acha do Samsung s8?
bom
ruim
péssimo

o que você acha do iPhone 8?
bom
ruim
péssimo
```

Como esta exibindo:

```
o que você acha do Samsung s8
bom

o que você acha do Samsung s8
ruim

o que você acha do Samsung s8
péssimo

o que você acha do iPhone 8?
bom

o que você acha do iPhone 8?
ruim

o que você acha do iPhone 8?
péssimo
```

Meu codigo

```
$id_categoria = $_GET['id'];
$tabela = duas_tabelas($id_categoria, $mysqli);

foreach($tabela as $resultado){
  echo $resultado[1]."";
  echo $resultado[2]."";
};
```

Na pagina funcao(onde esta as function).

```
function duas_tabelas($id_categoria, $mysqli) {
  if (isset($id_categoria)) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("faz a consulta");         
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_categoria);
    $stmt->execute();   
    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($pergunta, $opcao);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      $resultado = array($pergunta, $opcao);
      $resultss[] = $resultado;
    };

    return $resultss;
  };
};
```

Eu estou usando `INNER JOIN` para relacionar, depois uso `while` para montar um *array*. e na pagina de exibição eu um `foreach` para manipular o *array* que vem da `function`. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: coloca a query e o código php que está utilizando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu já tive esse problema e resolvi da seguinte utilizando um if para filtrar quando a pergunta for repetida, abaixo um exemplo mais ou menos como o código funcionaria

```
$id_categoria = $_GET['id'];
$tabela = duas_tabelas($id_categoria, $mysqli);
$filtro = $tabela[0,0]; //recebe a primeira pergunta da tabela.
echo $filtro."";

foreach($tabela as $resultado){
       if($filtro != $resultado[1]){
   echo $resultado[1]."";
   }
   echo $resultado[2]."";
   $filtro = $resultado[1]
  };
```

Comment: vou testar aqui

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou aqui. mas eu tenho uma dúvida, se eu quiser colocar isso em um form para uma enquete como eu faço?? <form>priemeira consulta aq</form> <form>segunda consulta aq</form

Comment: tentei mas não estou conseguindo

Comment: Galera esta muito complicado fazer isso, por favor uma aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quiser mudar a forma como o código de exibição é implementado você pode alterar a `query` para o seguinte:

```
SELECT x.tipo,
       x.id_pergunta,
       x.id_opcao,
       x.descricao
  FROM (SELECT 0 AS tipo,
               p.id_pergunta,
               NULL as id_opcao,
               p.descricao
          FROM pergunta p
         UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 AS tipo,
               o.id_pergunta,
               o.id_opcao,
               o.descricao
          FROM opcao) x
 ORDER BY x.tipo, x.id_pergunta, x.id_opcao
```

A melhor forma seria utilizar duas `querys`, uma para pergunta e uma para opção e alterar seu código `PHP` para mostrar a informação de forma correta.

Comment: Não seria ruim para banco de dados fazer duas consultas? estou pensando na demora para exibir essas consultas. como ficaria com duas consultas?? meu codigo é esse. na pagina exibir pesquisa. $tabela = unir_tabela($id_cotegoria, $mysqli);



foreach($tabela as $resultado){

 


echo $resultado[1]."</br>";

echo $resultado[2]."</br>";

  
 



};

Comment: @XiroNakamura não ficaria ruim, afinal são duas tabelas diferentes, na realidade não faria diferença porque o acesso seria igual. Quanto ao fato de exibir, você tem que mostrar primeiro como está seu código no `PHP` agora para podermos adaptar.

Comment: vou postar o código.